# Assign tags for dynamic UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, tags

I found this example of a dynamic view of `UIButton`s at: http://helpmecodeswift.com/advanced-functions/generating-uibuttons-loop

I inserted this code into my app but unfortunately I can't find a way to set a tag for each buttons.
My target is to know which button is tapped, count the amount of clicks for each button and save this information into my DB.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var arrayOfVillains = ["santa", "bugs", "superman", "batman"]

    var buttonY: CGFloat = 20
    for villain in arrayOfVillains {

        let villainButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
        buttonY = buttonY + 50  // we are going to space these UIButtons 50px apart

        villainButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  // get some fancy pantsy rounding
        villainButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        villainButton.setTitle("Button for Villain: \(villain)", forState: UIControlState.Normal) // We are going to use the item name as the Button Title here.
        villainButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(villain)"
        villainButton.addTarget(self, action: "villainButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(villainButton)  // myView in this case is the view you want these buttons added
    }
}

func villainButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {

    if sender.titleLabel?.text != nil {
        println("You have chosen Villain: \(sender.titleLabel?.text)")
    } else {

        println("Nowhere to go :/")

    }

}

}
```

So how it is possible to set and get the tag for/from each button in code (in this example)?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use enumerated array to access indexes of the current item in iteration and use that as a tag:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var arrayOfVillains = ["santa", "bugs", "superman", "batman"]

    var buttonY: CGFloat = 20  
    for (index, villain) in arrayOfVillains.enumerated() {

        let villainButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
        buttonY = buttonY + 50  // we are going to space these UIButtons 50px apart

        // set the tag to current index
        villainButton.tag = index

        villainButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10  // get some fancy pantsy rounding
        villainButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        villainButton.setTitle("Button for Villain: \(villain)", forState: UIControlState.Normal) // We are going to use the item name as the Button Title here.
        villainButton.titleLabel?.text = "\(villain)"
        villainButton.addTarget(self, action: "villainButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(villainButton)  // myView in this case is the view you want these buttons added
        }
    }       
}

@objc func villainButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {

    // tag of pressed button
    print(">>> you pressed button with tag: \(sender.tag)")

    if sender.titleLabel?.text != nil {
        println("You have chosen Villain: \(sender.titleLabel?.text)")
    } else {

        println("Nowhere to go :/")

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an integer-based for loop for this.

```
for i in 0 ..< arrayOfVillains.count {
    let villain = arrayOfVillains[i]
    let villainButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
    villainButton.tag = i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows,

```
var buttonTag = 1
for villain in arrayOfVillains {
   let villainButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
   villainButton.tag = buttonTag
   buttonTag += 1
}
```